# for loop error '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I want to make a for loop to do multiplications, and add `+` and `-` signs to each number.

```py
n = int(input("n : "))
list_num = [1]
a = 1

for i in range(n-1):
    a = a*-5
    if(a >= 0):
        a = '{0:+}'.format(a)
    list_num.append(a)

for x in list_num:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

I want to get a result like:

```
+1 -5 +25 -125 +625 -3125
```

but my Python code error like this

```py
if(a >= 0):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Please help to be able to resolve the error

Comment: `a = '{0:+}'.format(a)` turns `a` from an `int` into a `str`, so the following iteration fails with that error.  You should use a different variable name for the string-ized value.

Comment: You should append the formatted number to the list, not replace the variable with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a str to a:

```
if(a >= 0):
        a = '{0:+}'.format(a)
    list_num.append(a)
```

replace by

```
list_num.append('{0:+}'.format(a))
```

Comment: This won't append the negative numbers to the list. Get rid of the `if`.

Comment: Good point @Barmar. updating the answer